# Error: Ubuntu bionic is not supported hyperledger composer in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to install hyperledger composer on my machine Ubuntu 18.04

I am getting the below error

> Error: Ubuntu bionic is not supported hyperledger composer

Anyone help me how to solve this

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu 18.04 is supported by hyperledger fabric. try 16.04 instead.

Comment: Defects in Hyperledger Composer should be reported as GitHub issues. https://github.com/hyperledger/composer

Answer (score 12):

I have edited the `prereqs-ubuntu.sh` file like this

```
declare -a versions=('trusty' 'xenial' 'yakkety' 'bionic');
```

Its working...

Answer (score 4):

Hi you need to perform some changes in your ubuntu prerequisites 18.04.
Follow these simple steps.

1. Type nano prereqs-ubuntu.sh in your terminal.
2. Find the line 'Array of supported version'.
   Then changing the line ' `declare -a version=('trusty' 'xenial' 'yakkety');` '
   TO `declare -a version=('trusty' 'xenial' 'yakkety' 'bionic');`
   Then press ctrl z.

Your are done!!!

Answer (score 3):

The Hyperledger Composer [installation prerequisites](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html) page says clearly:

> The following are prerequisites for installing the required development tools:
>
> - Operating Systems: Ubuntu Linux 14.04 / 16.04 LTS (both 64-bit), or Mac OS 10.12
> - Docker Engine: Version 17.03 or higher
> - Docker-Compose: Version 1.8 or higher
> - Node: 8.9 or higher (note version 9 is not supported)
> - npm: v5.x
> - git: 2.9.x or higher
> - Python: 2.7.x
> - A code editor of your choice, we recommend VSCode.

Ubuntu 18.04 (code name "Bionic") is not supported. If you want to run Hyperledger Composer on Ubuntu you must install Ubuntu 16.04 (code name "Xenial").

Comment: I have edited the prereqs-ubuntu.sh file like this. declare -a versions=('trusty' 'xenial' 'yakkety' 'bionic'); It works..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows subsystem for linux.
Then try to edit the file as:

1. Type "nano prereqs-ubuntu.sh" in your terminal.
2. Change the array from

   `# Array of supported versions declare -a version=('trusty' 'xenial' 'yakkety')`

   #### To

   `# Array of supported versions declare -a versions=('trusty' 'xenial' 'yakkety', 'bionic', 'focal');`